# How to work with fragments in navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am facing quite a hard time implementing `fragments` in navigation. Once a user will click on item i want to show fragment that will be displayed in `FrameLayout`. But when i do that it shows me the content of parent activity even fragment is replaced in `FrameLayout`.

This is the xml of parent activity

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    tools:context="com.softoven.ultron.HomeActivity">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background_shadow"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
        <CheckedTextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/latest"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:text="LATEST" />
        <CheckedTextView
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/world"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"

            android:text="WORLD" />
        <CheckedTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/national"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:text="NATIONAL"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />
        <CheckedTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/business"
            android:text="BUSINESS"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />
        <CheckedTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/finance"
            android:text="FINANCE"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        />
   <!--these shouldn't cause any problem now since they aren't chlid of FrameLayout-->
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:menu="@menu/menu"
    app:itemTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"/>
```

and this is xml of fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.softoven.ultron.activities.BookmarkActivity">
    <ListView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bookmarks">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the code that i use for fragment transaction.

```
@Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                item.setChecked(true);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.news:
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "News", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.bookmarks:
                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_container,new BookmarkFragment()).commit();
                        return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

Some help would be appricated. Thanks!

Comment: `FragmentTransaction`s only handle `Fragment`s. They will not replace/remove any `View`s not in a `Fragment`. If you want the `View`s in the `FrameLayout` removed, you'll have to do it yourself, or put them in a `Fragment` that you load upon startup, in which case the transactions will work as you're expecting.

Comment: check this link
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: I have updated the question. kindly look into it. Now i don't have child to framelayout but still i get same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `FrameLayout` has `Views` as children. The replace method will replace only prior fragments, if any added in the `FrameLayout` NOT the views.

To solve this, you could remove, the children from the `FrameLayout` and add it to a separate `Fragment`. Then add that `Fragment` in the `FrameLayout` as its only child in your XML.

Then when you `replace` the `Fragment` it will eventually get replaced.

Comment: Ok now i have removed the views from framelayout. and i am getting the same result

Comment: Does your `listView` contain data? Because the `ListView` is positioned at the same place as the `FrameLayout`. If it contains data, it will overlap the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: that would be a problem i might have data in listview sometime and sometimes i won't have it. I think i need to add other views in fragment too

Comment: Hey  i have one question. I'll have to add very first fragment in framelayout or replace?

Comment: `add` or `replace` wont make a difference when adding the first fragment. Because [add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add) just adds the fragment to the container, where as [replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace) first removes any Fragments which may be already present in the container, and then adds the passed Fragment.

Comment: Thanks brother. Your answer helped me really well. Can you guide me how to change the tittle of customize toolbar from fragment. Every fragment have different tittles in toolbar

Comment: You're welcome. Assuming your activity is `AppCompatActivity`, in your fragments, you could use this line: `((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");`

Comment: but i am using custom toolbar. which has a textview as centered title

Comment: In that case, you could maintain a reference to that `TextView` in your `Activity` and access the `TextView` using a getter, something like this: `((MyActivity)getActivity()).getMyTitleTextView().setText("My Title");`

Comment: Ok i have made a method which holds the reference of textview of toolbar. But i can't access that method with getActivity

Comment: As shown in my example, you have to cast it using your activity name.

Comment: I got it. Thanks man you saved my day. I wish if i could vote you 10 more times. This community has many programmer but its hard to find programmers like you. Stay blessed

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```